# Which are the best course to learn automated QA for a start-up?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, manual-testing, load-testing, agile-testing

Which courses are the best to help me grasp the foundations of Automated testing? I am currently in a manual QA position doing only Ad-Hoc/regression testing. This is also the only testing we currently, but I realize it is important to implement automated testing as well as the company grows.

I have basic development skills - HTML, CSS, and some Javascript which from what I've read, will help me along my way of learning automated testing.

Do I use Selenium? Do I write my own scripts? Do I use both? How does automated testing differ for web/mobile applications? I've looked at AST, but none of the reading I've done has answered these questions for me.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Refer this : http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/6742/what-do-i-need-to-start-from-zero-in-automated-testing

Answer (score 2):

Instead of voting for closing I am going to use your question as an example to how not to ask questions.

How are we supposed to know what do you need ? we don't know what the product is, what are the company's future plans for the product or testing, what is the budget and how much time do you have or can spend automating stuff, what's your priorities, how much do you need to cover out of the unknown product you have and how much are you willing to sacrifice for doing it using software, how often do you need to test now and how often does the company want to test (mine is testing a new build almost every minute), how important is reporting back results and in what format, how long does a test cycle takes and many other questions.

There is no such thing as **automated QA**, there are tasks that you can replace with code and tasks that you cannot.

So what should you do next ? break the problem to smaller parts and try to find a solution for each one of them, then try to find a common solution for all.

Comment: "We introduce Selenium to new users and we do not assume prior Selenium experience. We do assume, however, that the user has at least a basic understanding of test automation."                                                            This is what I've been reading in the Selenium handbook. A basic understanding of test automation is all I'm looking to have. For now at least. Thank you for your questions. These were questions I had to, I wasn't necessarily looking for the answers.