# Appium: Same code is working Sometimes and failing Sometimes

Tags: java, android, appium

I'm using the following code to run a simple test. The same code is working sometimes and returning error sometimes. The error it will return is "Not able to find UI Element".

This is my code:

```
package example;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;

public class CalculatorTest {
AppiumDriver<WebElement> driver;

@BeforeClass
public void setUp() throws Exception {

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "6.0");
    capabilities.setCapability("app", "C:/Users/rraghunath/Downloads/Apk/Calculator_com.google.android.calculator.apk");
    capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.google.android.calculator");
    capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.android.calculator2.CalculatorGoogle");

    driver = new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
}

@AfterClass
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
}

/**
* Test for Calculator
*/
@Test
public void test_CalculatorTest(){

   driver.findElement(By.id("digit_1")).click();
   driver.findElement(By.id("digit_0")).click();
   driver.findElement(By.id("digit_1")).click();
   driver.findElement(By.id("del")).click();
   driver.findElement(By.id("del")).click();
   driver.findElement(By.id("del")).click();
   driver.findElement(By.id("digit_1")).click();
   driver.findElement(By.id("dec_point")).click();
   driver.findElement(By.id("digit_0")).click();
   driver.findElement(By.id("digit_2")).click();
   driver.findElement(By.id("digit_3")).click();
   driver.findElement(By.id("op_mul")).click();
   driver.findElement(By.id("digit_3")).click();
   driver.findElement(By.id("dec_point")).click();
   driver.findElement(By.id("digit_0")).click();
   driver.findElement(By.id("digit_1")).click();
   driver.findElement(By.id("digit_2")).click();
   driver.findElement(By.id("eq")).click();

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for the elements to be visible or clickable before clicking on them. It is possible that the application is sometimes a bit slower with drawing and that the element is just not there yet when it tries to click.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("digit_1"));
driver.findElement(By.id("digit_1")).click();
```

This will wait for 30 seconds until the digit_1 element is clickable.
Often waiting for the first element on the page is enough, for each transition to a new page use a new wait.

Code sample from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28799420/how-to-wait-to-activity-using-appium-on-begin-and-during-test-itself

Answer (score 0):

Agree - wait should be introduce before any action. Best practices will be to use implicit wait

- **Each time it wont happen** that **element will be Clickable**
- I'll suggest to use "**ExpectedConditions.visibility**" instead of "ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable"
- This solution will work for each and every scenario **irrespective of action**

  ```
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(By.id("digit_1"));
  driver.findElement(By.id("digit_1")).click();
  ```

Comment: The best practise is to NOT use implicit wait, but explicit. implicit has all kinds of issues. http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12583/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-use-implicit-wait-in-selenium-webdriver-should-one-use

Comment: Using element visibility is also not a good idea when you want to click it. It could be visible but not clickable, because some animation is still happening. This has been the cause of a lot of flaky tests in the past in my experience.

Comment: Implicit wait : Its having issues is different case, dont you think? It becomes bad practices when one is keeping max. seconds. But what those who are using smaller delays?

Comment: For this question : Anywhere you seen "click" is failing is addressed? What I am concern about is "ExpectedConditions.visibility" is more generalize and can be use many time for all elements instead of "ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable"

Comment: Implicit has way more issues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404160/when-to-use-explicit-wait-vs-implicit-wait-in-selenium-webdriver/28067495#28067495 In the end it always about choise, pick what works for you, but be aware of possible consquences.

Comment: Thats right. What working is important one but not best practices :) Appreciated, shared issues list.

Answer (score 0):

FluentWait  wait= new FluentWait (d);
Wait.pollingEvery (200,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
wait.withTimeouts (5,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
wait.ignoring (noSuchElementException.class);
wait.until (ExpectedCondtions.visibilityOf (By.id ("digit_1"));

Answer (score -1):

If that program is all about waiting statement. I would suggest u should go for implicit wait
E.g-

```
driver.manage().timeouts ().implicitlyWait (20,TIMEUNIT.SECONDS);
```

Comment: This is a bad practise, maybe easier to implement, but this will leads to issues, like slower test runs. http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12583/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-use-implicit-wait-in-selenium-webdriver-should-one-use

Comment: Then you should go for

Comment: Then you should go for FLUENT WAIT

Comment: If you think the syntax is to verbose, it is also what the linked question suggests

Comment: FluentWait <webDriver> wait= new FluentWait <webDriver>(d);

Answer (score -2):

What about adding  `Thread.Slepp(<time from milliseconds >)` before starting the find `elemant` commands.

Comment: Sleeps are anti-pattern: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/3764/what-are-some-examples-of-why-explicitly-sleep-statements-are-bad