# How to click on an element in pop-up?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, java, javascript

[image]

I want to click on the highlighted English Element but unable to click on that. Actually its a pop-up wind appear when i click on the some button. But my main concern is that I'm unable to click on that "English" Button. I'm sharing my HTML code and help must be appreciated thanks.

```
<div id="references-materialSelector" class="lscomponent-initialized ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="text-align: left;">
<div id="folder1177" class="folder">English</div>
```

Comment: id & class is not helping you to click on it?

Comment: yeah id and class are not working any help?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.99)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426923 (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 184 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-LU4RI93', ip: '10.100.154.5', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_111'

Comment: I have answered here, for case - when element is not yet visible. Refer http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/24207/appium-same-code-is-working-sometimes-and-failing-sometimes

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that your `id="folder1177"` is not dynamic? If yes, then selecting by ID must work.

Potential issues:

1. Element might be NOT YET visible. You can try waiting. Debug to see if waiting helps before adding it.
2. Element might NOT be visible. I can see a scrollbar and English link being somewhere in the middle. Try scrolling to the element.
3. Check HTML to see if frames are not used. If it is, you will have to switch to frame.  [Know-How](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879206/how-to-switch-between-frames-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java)

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on pop up and see is there any frame available.
2. You need to switch to alert. Alert alert= driver.switchTo().alert();