# How to tell protractor to wait for each command for 3 seconds

Tags: protractor, angular, e2e, typescript

I am running angular e2e scripts.

I am adding explicit wait for every element.

Instead, is it possible to tell protractor to delay 3 seconds for every command?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share your code.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use the implicitlyWait option, although it has been removed from the Protractor documentation:

```
onPrepare: function(){
    browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3000);
},
```

Code example from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33299567/where-to-put-implicitlywait-in-protractor

**Read this!!!**: [Is it a bad practice to use implicit wait in Selenium Webdriver? Should one use only explicit wait?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12583/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-use-implicit-wait-in-selenium-webdriver-should-one-use)

**Alternatively**:

Wrap your driver/browser in your own helper class and implement your own "`findElement()`" method which always does an explicitWait.

My [pageObjects](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/PageObject.html) action methods start with a wait for the first element and then expect the other elements to be there:

```
    internal string ActionOnPage() {
        wait.ForElement(By.Id("uniqueid1")).SendKeys("sometext");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("uniqueid2")).Click();
    }
```

This `wait.ForElement()` is just a wrapper around the driver:

```
    public IWebElement ForElement(By by, int seconds = 10)
    {
        var wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds));
        return wait.Until(f => f.FindElement(by));
    }
```

The example is in C#, but I think it translates to JavaScript/Protractor

Answer (score 1):

**No, You should NOT use static waits, it is a bad practice. Instead...Read below**

Disclaimer : I am an actual Protractor SDET, who has been using Protractor from last couple of years in actual Large Projects.

Using Hard coded waits(static wait) along with every statement is an very bad practice for multiple reasons:

- It slows down the whole batch execution, particularly visible if you are running thousands of tests(like me!)
- It still does not give guarantee that it will work in scenarios where application is even more slower.

#### Instead Use Dynamic Promise based waits because:

- RELIABLE: It is always reliable as it waits till object/state is resolved through promise.
- FASTER: it only relies on actual object availability so it is **generally 10 times faster** if implemented correctly  and application response time is reasonable
- Using DRY principle can be implemented globally by a single function.

Code Example:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
// Waits for the element with id 'abc' to be clickable.
browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable($('#abc')), 5000);
```

Or may be you can generalize as common function:

```
function genericWait(expectedCondition) {
  return browser.wait(expectedCondition, 3000).then(function() {
    return true;
  }, function() {
    return false;
  });
}
```

And then it can be resolved using an expect(from jasmine framework)

```
expect(genericWait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(locator))).toBe(true);
```

[Protractor Documentation Reference](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.elementToBeClickable)