# How to handle windows authentication pop up with Protractor?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, javascript, protractor

**Use case:**

When URL loads, it request for Windows authentication (Enter Username and Password). How it goes is:

1. loads the url
2. on clicking Post button in the page. Windows Authentication pops up appears asking for username and password.

   [image]

**Tried:**

Installed AutoIT and written script and generated a exe file.

**Question**

1. How to call this in protractor javascript? Something like `runtime.getruntime.exe("path/.exe")`
2. Or is their any another way to achieve it.
3. Highly appreciate, if you explain at code level as well as I am new to javascript.

Comment: Are you sure you have to do it with AutoIT? You can specify the username and a password inside the URL string, try it out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24305626/771848.

Comment: Usecase : 1)loads the url 2)on clicking Post button in the page. Windows Authentication pops up appears asking for username and password.

Comment: @alecxe ,tested again. it did worked after entering username and password in url.  Next is, How to verify the json response ?

Comment: @alecxe isn't this not recommended? I think Chrome starting version 59, has blocked passing URL with username and password.

Comment: @demouser123 yeah, I think both Chrome and IE dropped support for that, I am a bit out of date on that. But, thanks, good to know.

Comment: thanks guys, i am testing against Chrome Browser. Is their any alternative solution/Approach. that get work with chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround (had similar issues with selenium) was to use Firefox, and create a browser profile that includes a password and let the browser populate the login screen.

Firefox (I have successfully implemented these steps)

- [Firefox Create
  profile](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Creating_a_new_Firefox_profile_on_Windows)
- [Firefox use profile in
  selenium](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/custom-firefox-profile/)

Chrome (Suggestions, i have not tried configuring Chrome profiles before)

- [Chrome Profile](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/95606?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)
- Unsure how to [configure selenium with Chrome profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15272785/selenium-chrome-attach-default-profile)

Comment: thanks dan, My Test cases runs against chrome browser. Is their any solution for the same.

Comment: Chrome also has similar feature Settings > Manage Passwords. might just have to play with the feature to see if chrome will autologin or if you still need to click the ok button. (Here is someone-elses answer on another post: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12403/selenium-code-for-login-popup-window-page#answer-20409

Comment: Hi Keasav, How did you go getting it working? if its working please close the question by marking this question as answered.

Comment: Hi Dan, Currently it worked in chrome entering usernamen and password in URL [ browser.driver.get("https://username:Pass@genqa/site/showGeoLocation/");]. i have latest chrome. And i am looking for ur steps. creating profile that includes password. Do u have any sample code how to achieve this (create a browser profile that includes username and password.)

Comment: Hi Keasav, I have configured Firefox (see links). But have not configured Selenium to use a specific Chrome profile before. hence i have added some links that will get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Based on these two questions- [How to handle authentication in Chrome 59](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44542740/chrome-59-and-basic-authentication-with-selenium-fluentlenium) and [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44531972/chrome-59-support-for-basic-auth-credentials-in-urls-alternative-for-usage-with), I think hitting a previous page with the authentication credentials,before the actual authentication page, makes Chrome remember the credentials and then you can use it afterwards.

I haven't implemented this and so I'm not hundred percent sure of this, but you can give it a try.

Also, when you say that you have latest Chrome and you're able to pass [username:Pass@genqa/site/showGeoLocation‌​/");]](http://username:Pass@genqa/site/showGeoLocation%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B/%22);]), I would think that you should report this to Google, if you're Chrome is above 59, since as per [this](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5669008342777856) post, support for this has been dropped entirely.

Comment: Thanks demouser123. sounds interesting reading, particular the second with different credentials. login on chrome now on my bucket list.

Comment: hi @demouser123, i reported to google. they justified saying the below.    "The changes we made somewhat recently blocked embedded credentials in subresource requests only, not in top-level navigations."     So passing username and password in url is valid.

Answer (score 0):

what's the problem with the code ?

```
                  handlePromise = browser.driver.getAllWindowHandles();
                  var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve,handles) {
                        try {

                        var count=handles.length;
                        console.log("Count F: " +count) ;
                      // var newWindow = handles[count-1];
                        var newWindow = handles[count];
                        browser.driver.switchTo().window(newWindow);
                        browser.sleep(9000);
                        browser.driver.getWindowHandle();
                        browser.driver.executeScript('window.focus();');
                        console.log("Count S: " +count) ;
                        resolve(true);

                        } catch (error) {

                          console.log(error);
                        }


                    });


                    promise1.then(function(value) {
                      try {

                        console.log("promise value from p1" + value);
                        console.log("operation Function");
                      //  browser.actions().click();
                        browser.actions().sendKeys('user01@group.org').perform();
                        browser.sleep(9000);

                      } catch (error) {

                        console.log(error);
                      }

                    });
```