# How to export test cases in the latest selenium IDE

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-ide, qa-developer

How do I export test cases in the latest version of Selenium IDE? There is no export option in the file menu.

[image: Selenium IDE]

Comment: What Firefox version do you use? Selenium IDE does not work anymore in newer versions of Firefox.

Comment: @Patrick, Selenium IDE's making a comeback and is now supported by Firefox and Chrome (though I haven't tried it yet) - OP seems to be using the Chrome version.

Comment: Ah i missed that. On the website i do see a new IDE, but no announcement. Since when is it back?

Answer (score 4):

This feature is not available in Selenium IDE new version. Try Katalon Recorder if you really need that function. Among Selenium-IDE alike tools, at this moment it is the only one with code export.

[Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/katalon-automation-record/ljdobmomdgdljniojadhoplhkpialdid?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon)

[Firefox extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/katalon-automation-record/)

[Introduction video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KBI1NZAICK4)

The following languages and frameworks are supported:

- C# (MSTest and NUnit)
- Java (TestNG and JUnit)
- Ruby (RSpec)
- Python (unittest)
- AppDynamics
- Groovy (Katalon Studio)
- Robot Framework
- XML

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The new selenium IDE does not have code export yet.

The solution is to use the **Katalon** (3rd party, closed source) Selenium IDE. As of today, it is the only new IDE with code export, see the [Selenium IDE comparison](https://a9t9.com/blog/selenium-ide-2018/) here.

Answer (score 0):

The new Selenium IDE opens within a browser window, so the dropdown you're looking at is just a Chrome browser dropdown. From what I can see - there is no way of exporting tests from this version.

I'd suggest that you download Firefox ESR (Extended Support Release) and install the old Selenium IDE plug-in. Open your tests there and then export them like the good ol' days.