# Learning Java & selenium

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, java, learning

I have recently started learning selenium and Java. I need your assistance as to how should i go about it.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please ask specific questions as to what issues you are having, what you have done and what you need to focus on learning, please.

Comment: Hi Paul, Thanks for your reply...i have recently moved from Manual Testing to Automation and have never worked on any programming language before..hence i seek guidance from all starting from basics in programming/java, selenium...websites...video/online tutorials...practice program mes...etc.i know i am being 'Generic' again and also understand practice is the only key. But systematic approach would help me learn more rather than doing things wayward.

Comment: Asking for such advice does not really fit the format of Stack Exchange is the issue. For your question there can be 7 or 8 correct answers. Ask multiple specific questions and you will get much better answers. For example, 'How do I learn Selenium' would be bad though asking for principles behind the page object model would be useful and good. Asking for guidelines to development is bad, asking for examples of Selenium (or even googling it) would be slightly better and for the best results start trying and when hitting a snag ask a question about what issue you are having.

Comment: OP: You really need to get more comfortable with google search engine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does one get started with web test automation using Selenium?](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/11785/how-does-one-get-started-with-web-test-automation-using-selenium)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to SQA. This is a broad question as there is no particular start point- where you can start as a learner in here. However, I would like to give you few tips .

As you have not mentioned whether you have a prior knowledge of Java or not, so I am basing my assumption that you're a newbie.

Step 1 : Clear your Java basics. Start from the bottom and work your way up. Since Selenium doesn't requires a whole lot of complex Java code (until absolutely necessary, you should be good to go once you have a good, firm knowledge of Core Java basics.

Get a good book and practice more to have a good code flow. You can roughly follow this pattern :

- Data types and variables
- Learn about the operators and operations they perform
- How to add Decision making statements
- Arrays
- Using Loops for multiple iterations
- Classes and Objects
- Constructors
- String and String operations
- File and File operations

This should be enough for you to start with.

Step 2 : Learning Selenium should be easy once you have gone through Java. But, remember that it is not always about coding only.

Start with basics- like setting up the Webdriver (many people fail here and this is the most tricky part).

Once you're done, start with learning the basic operations (opening a web page, running your test across different browsers- one at a time, filling forms etc.). Learn how the code works, how the web elements are recognized and interacted with.

Then work your way up to using waits, handling JS alert boxes and such. Gradually try implementing your knowledge in your daily work and it will help you learn more.

Then you can dive into stuff like handling multiple windows, tabs, modal windows, iframes, keyboard events, mouse hover over.

I would suggest you have a good book by your side to clear you concepts, and there are a lot of tutorials on the web, which will help you out. In case of any issues you face with, there are people over here that will always help you out (#SoReadyToHelp). Feel free to ask a question if you're stuck somewhere.

My recommendation :

Online tutorials : [ToolSQA](http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/selenium-tutorial-selenium-webdriver-tutorials/) has one of the detailed and best step by step tutorials. [Guru99](http://www.guru99.com/selenium-tutorial.html) is another one. [This](http://www.amazon.in/Selenium-Webdriver-Java-Learn-Examples/dp/1495450201) is a good book to start you with.

Comment: There is a very good link with structured process for Selenium learning http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/11785/how-does-one-get-started-with-web-test-automation-using-selenium . Please see answer by @Yamikuronue

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to selenium group. Make sure you are strong in OOPS concepts and core Java. Selenium gives you power to automate web applications and soon you're going to get that power. At early stage only start automating your day to day browsing activities like opening and logging into your social websites, sending mail to a friend etc. Not to worry it is an easy tool to learn.

Comment: You should be careful while using your words. This is not a Selenium group of any sorts.