# Self learners: Selenium

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, learning

Here are many testers who aspire to become automation testers using selenium. They pick random websites and create test scripts as per their own understanding.

They are good at programming using Core Java. But working on a well-organized automation project provides more exposure to different frameworks and other aspects of automation testing. By other aspects, I mean taking screenshots, logging, dealing with frames.

What all features a self learning automation QA should implement before he can consider himself good at automation?

I am giving a few examples myself:

1. Capture screenshots at failure
2. Use logger
3. Handle pop ups
4. perform read/write operations from files like txt, xls, xlsx, xml etc.

Comment: one important skill is using search engines. It would give you answers like https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/11785/how-does-one-get-started-with-web-test-automation-using-selenium and https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/27418/i-want-to-become-a-software-qa-from-where-i-can-start Show us your own research, and how your question is different from already asked

Comment: Start by becoming a competent programmer in any language you can get any help locally. If no local help is available, start with Python - widely considered best first language for beginners. Plenty of free online courses. Don't try any shortcuts, there aren't any. Many questions we get here are trivially answerable with minimal programming experience.

Comment: Selenium is just one of libraries you will have to learn to use with your language of choice. You will have to learn to use dozens more. Selenium is NOT a problem: programming is.

Comment: First of all, Apologies. I should have made the question more clear. Updating it.

Comment: Please provide more detail on "different frameworks and other aspects of automation testing." as that is very broad and general and hard to provide a specific answer to

Comment: As you found out, we have "Closing mafia" running amok, looking for questions to close. Many questions are low quality (as your's was before edit), but I nominated it to reopening after edit. It is **still** a bit too wide, IMHO.

Comment: Thank you, Peter! Let me see if I can contain it further.. Thanks again. Cheers!

Comment: If your question will remain closed, don't worry: You are on the correct path. Few additional skills which you did not mentioned are: (1) designing data structures (2) using appropriate design patterns (3) refactoring. Wikipedia is good start to read about them. Important part is that you **are** concerned about improving your general programming skills, not only solving basic trivial problems, like many other questioners are. It takes many years of practice to become a master.

Comment: The term Automation means not only opening a browser and verifying some image existence on the page (essentially what Selnium does in addition to the functional testing). Good automation specialist can handle multiple tasks for different layers (API, Database, Continuous Integration).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of items from my side:

1. Thread safe classes to be able to safely parallellize test execution
2. Working with database (at least relational database) (Tools for injecting and reading the data from/to databases)
3. Parsing xml since there could be scenario steps or steps data described in xml
4. Parsing text using regular expressions since it often happens that one need to extract a part of the string or match the string using certain rules
5. Use matchers like hamcrest
6. Use JavascriptExecutor from Selenium
7. Have mastered both Page Object Model approach and the regular approach
8. Have mastered practices of conversion one objects into another
9. Have mastered practices of serializing and de-serializing the objects