# Universities teaching Software Quality Assurance & Testing?

Tags: learning, training, qa-role

I found that starting in software testing often requires a degree in a computer science related subject, but I can't find any QA only degrees. I understand the importance of prior computing knowledge (and therefore subjects like Computer Science is a relevant and appropriate pre-requisite), but rather than obtaining a degree in a generic field like Computing and Technology, does anyone know of a degree that focuses purely on software testing?

So my question is: Are there any UK-based Universities that teach Software Quality Assurance and Testing? I'm really looking for a course that offers a degree in the field, rather than just a module contained within a more generic course.

Hope that makes sense.

**Edit:** I've read a few articles on whether the need for Software Testing courses exists or not ([here's one from SmartBear](http://blog.smartbear.com/testing/why-not-train-testers-early-with-software-testing-degrees/)) and it seems the community's in two minds about it. Personally, I see courses on Development all the time and, with the rise of technology and the need for Quality Assurance, I'm of the mindset that we should  develop careers for Software Testers. I mean, it's a legitimate career and the industry's crying out for more QA, so do you think we should support, encourage and share knowledge with those who want to become testers?

Comment: I dont think any special degree available for specific QA. It is part of IT degree as subject. After that you can do certification in diff. QA level ISTQB exams..

Comment: @HelpingHands - yeah, and that's kind of my point... there are endless development and programming degrees available but a lack of software testing courses when it's (arguably) just as an important area to specialise in. I realise it's easy to argue / defend that statement as a tester, but I could probably find some whitepapers somewhere to back it up ;)

Comment: University professors are still recommending that developers start in testing - see this question: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/3238/fundamental-requirements-for-an-entry-level-qa-engineer?rq=1 While that misunderstanding exists, the likelihood of any dedicated SQA degrees existing is rather small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, no  UK-based university offers a degree exclusively in software testing.  If there were such a degree plan, you would find it in Google search results, along with all other degree plans at UK-based universities.

There are other ways to get an education that is relevant to software testing, however.